# Attoparsec efficient parser for multiple char

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

If I define

```
charToText :: Char -> Text
charToText c = pack [c]

anyCharParser :: Parser Text
anyCharParser = mconcat <$> manyTill (charToText <$> anyChar) endOfInput
```

it seems to me that lifting `charToText` is inefficient, because for each character matched `charToText` creates a singleton list to pack it as a `Text`.

Is there or more efficient way to do it ? For example a `Parser Text` that matches any single character ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
anyCharParser :: Parser Text
anyCharParser = pack <$> manyTill anyChar endOfInput
```