# Efficient attoparsec parser combinating general parsers and anyChar

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

*This is similar to my previous question [Attoparsec efficient parser for multiple char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75395223/attoparsec-efficient-parser-for-multiple-char/75396914#75396914), but I oversimplified the example parser I provided. I really apologize if it is considered spamming.*

If I define

```
charToText :: Char -> Text
charToText c = pack [c]

parseEqStarMonad :: Parser Text
-- I will not define it here, but it could be any Parser Text

envParser :: Parser Text
envParser = mconcat <$> many (parseEqStarMonad <|> (charToText <$> anyChar))
```

it seems to me that lifting `charToText` is inefficient, because for each character matched `charToText` creates a singleton list to pack it as a `Text`.

Is there or more efficient way to perform this parsing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `singleton c` instead of `pack [c]`. But beyond that, I don't see any obvious improvement.

This is fine if `mconcat` is used sparsely. If you need to append a lot of `Text` together, you should use a [`Builder`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0.1/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Builder.html) instead.